# nested controllers URL structure in Yii

Tags: php, yii

I was wondering what's the best way to have a nested URL structure in Yii
I have a website with a structure like the following

```
/index
/dashboard (dashboard controller, index action)
/dashboard/profile (profile controller, index action)
/dashboard/profile/view (profile controller, view action)
/dashboard/profile/update (profile controller, update action)
/dashboard/stats (stats controller, index action)
```

and so on...

Basically /dashboard has it's own controller and by default will use the Index action
however I would like to nest other controllers under /dashboard, e.g. /dashboard/profile
however, the /profile controller is not an action, it should be a controller which in turn can have it's own actions. e.g. /dashboard/profile/view

is this doable? if yes, what would be the best way to achieve such a structure?

Comment: You are probably looking to use a [module](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.module).

Comment: In MVC that the URL defines the structure i.e. `controller/action/parameter` is the basic structure of MVC. ext element after 1st slash will be taken as function name

Comment: @Ahmed isn't it possible to have the URL structure re-disegned so that  /dashboard/profile will be translated to /profile (controller) ?

Comment: I t is. But then you will have to move into the directories as we do for admin side in our websites.

Comment: @Ahmed what you are describing seems a good solution for what I am trying to achieve. Extra directory levels would actually be helpful for me.
Any tips regarding the url rewriting rules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have followed the [tutorial on the Yii site](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url#hiding-x-23x) to hide index.php from your application:

```
'urlManager' => array(
    'urlFormat' => 'path',
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'caseSensitive' => false,
    'rules' => array(

        'dashboard/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '/dashboard/<controller>/<action>',
        'dashboard/<controller:\w+>' => '/dashboard/<controller>/index',

        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:\w+>/' => '<controller>/index',

        ...
```

Comment: that seems all good and thank you for that, however the dashboard controller is still called. I get a 404 page unless I specify an action within the dashboard controller DashboardController.php E.g. actionProfile().
Whereas I would like the profile controller ProfileController.php to be called

Comment: It's weird, I have managed to make it work by setting 'caseSensitive' to true. Whenever it's set to false I get a 404 with Unable to resolve the request "Profile/index"

Comment: ok @Samuel Liew solved, I never realized before that controller files should only have the first letter uppercase e.g. ProfileviewController and not ProfileViewController

Also, managed to simply the first two rules to 

   'dashboard/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>', AND 
        'dashboard/<controller:\w+>' => '<controller>/index',

Answer (score 2):

There is one more way that probably wasn't mentioned. Yesterday I would answer "use modules" but today I learned (and tested) that it is enough to add sub-folders to folder "controllers" and "views". For example folder: "/controllers/dashboard" with file "ProfileController.php" will enable URL: "myproject.com/dashboard/profile/action" and views will be searched in folder "views/dashboard".

But there is the problem, that you cannot use URL: "myproject.com/dashboard/" as "dashboard" is only a folder name. So you will probably have to use modules.

[YouTube::Kurt Clement - Yii - UrlManager](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7EMnNJykijI)